# How to easily run a python script from Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to easily run a currently active python file in Visual Studio? I'm used to Notepad++ in which I had customized it to run an active python file in cmd on ctrl+r which made testing code very easy and fast. If there was something similar I could do for Visual Studio, that would be wonderful.

Thanks!

Comment: you referring to Visual Studio Code - the free editor?

Comment: I'm referring to "Visual Studio" which is also free, @jmh

Comment: Also I made sure to install the python workload when I installed Visual Studio just now

Comment: What I want really is a shortcut.

Comment: my answer below may not work for Visual Studio.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the extension 'Code Runner'. You may need to restart visual studio code after loading. Open your script in an editor window. Hit the keys 'control-alt-n' and your script should run. I just checked it on my mac and it ran fine.